# Create a pull request of a single commit on github

Tags: git, github

I see that similar questions have been asked many times, but I still don't understand and I need a practical example for my case.

I have a github repo with two branches:

1. `master` which is my development branch and where I want to push all latest changes and new features
2. `stable` where I want to push bug fixings only until new features have been tested.

Now I have made 4 commits and pushed them to `master`. First three commits are new features, last commit is a bug fixing.

In github, if I select `stable` branch, it shows that it is 4 commits behind master (which is correct).

Now I want **last commit only** to be pushed to stable branch. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cherry-pick the `last-commit-hash` in your `stable` branch and push to remote.

```
$ git fetch
$ git log                               # copy the last-commit-hash 

$ git checkout -b stable origin/stable  # create local/stable branch from remote/stable
$ git cherry-pick <last-commit-hash>    # take the last-commit
$ git push origin HEAD                  # update remote/stable
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I finally understand! :)

Comment: I followed these instructions and was able to get to work once, but now when I do it I'm still seeing my previous commits in the history. 

I created a feature branch from master and then created another branch to push as a pull request. 

I then did the cherry-pick from the feature branch. When I push it to git though I'm still seeing my previous commit messages as opposed to just my last one.

Any idea where I'm getting lost at?

Master(Branch) => Feature(Branch) => Pull Request(Branch with cherry-pick)

Comment: @ski760 I think you need to create a new branch from `master` branch (not from `feature`). Then cerry-pick the commit to the new branch.

Comment: @SajibKhan I created a new branch from master, but when I went to do the pull request I'm still seeing previous commits. :-( 

I created the branch, did a cherry-pick, and then I get the git commit --allow-empty message. I tried it before and it seemed to work just fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: @ski760 that means the changes you have in cherry-pick's commit already exists in `master` branch. Can you check if the changes are already in `master` branch?

Comment: @SajibKhan Yes the changes already do exist in master. Is there a different approach if they do? Really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: @ski760 Yes, one of the solution is `git revert`. Checkout a branch from `master` and revert the commit's you don't want (git revert <commit-hash>).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You can use git cherry-pick to apply a single commit by itself to your current branch.

```
git checkout stable
git cherry-pick <last_commit_id>
```

**Background:**

git cherry-pick  will apply the changes made in an existing commit to another branch, while recording a new commit. Essentially, you can copy commits from branch to branch.

Given the following tree

```
dd2e86 - 946992 - 9143a9 - a6fd86 - 5a6057 [master]
           \
            76cada - 62ecb3 - b886a0 [feature]
```

Let's say we want to copy b886a0 to master (on top of 5a6057).

We can run

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick b886a0
Now our tree will look something like:

dd2e86 - 946992 - 9143a9 - a6fd86 - 5a6057 - a66b23 [master]
           \
            76cada - 62ecb3 - b886a0 [feature]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to selectively take commits from another branch so this sounds exactly like what cherry-pick is supposed to do. Just checkout stable and do `git cherry-pick <commit hash>`

As for why, you may want to read on git workflows, specifically the one called gitflow. It seems to me like you need a branch like feature in which you do bug fixes and the it can be merged back into the "stable" mainline. Here you just do a gitmerge whereas when you mix feature development and bug fixes in the same branch you run into your situation where you have to cherrypick and carefully ignore commits for new features to get to the bug fix commits that you want.